# Why is rainfall uniform even though clouds exist in lumps?

Tags: everyday-life

Since clouds exist in lumps and are non-uniformly distributed, one would expect rainfall to be non-uniform as well. But as far as I can tell, rainfall is more or less uniform over a large region.

I suspect that turbulence might be at play here and cause the dispersal of raindrops, but I'm not really sure.

**EDIT**: I agree that rainfall is non-uniform as well but the non-uniformity of cloud distribution doesn't seem to commensurate with the rainfall. In other words, the cloud distribution appears to be much more uneven than the rainfall, but maybe that's just an illusion. Perhaps a better question might be, "is rainfall as non-uniform as the cloud distribution? If not, then why?".

Comment: Images from a Doppler radar normally show geographic variation in rainfall intensity within a storm. Over a large region, rainfall is non-uniform - as a storm rolls through, you can see rainfall intensity increase, peak, and then diminish, which is a result of rain-heavy clouds passing overhead. It's only over a *small* region that rainfall will be reasonably uniform. In some weather events, you can have a deluge in one location and not a single drop just a few miles away.

Comment: In my neck of the woods, you can look out across the Rio Grande valley and see isolated thunderstorms here and there, with blue sky in between. And the intensity of rain certainly varies even under 100% cloud conditions. Rainfall is not uniform.

Comment: Yes rainfall is non-uniform as well but what I want to ask is that the non-uniformity of clouds and the rainfall (in a small region) doesn't seem to commensurate. Perhaps that's just an illusion.

Comment: The most extreme example of non-uniform rainfall I ever saw was once driving along a several miles of straight road in open flat country. One half of the road was covered with water from a recent rain storm. The other half was completely dry.

Comment: If want to ask why the two things don't seem commensurate to you we're going to have to start discussing how to measure and compare cloud uniformity and rain uniformity. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not physics

Comment: To the extent that rainfall is less lumpy than clouds, perhaps it's because clouds move.

Answer (score 1):

Rainfall uniformity is dependent on the cloud structure that gives rise to it. For cold fronts and thunderstorms, the rain-causing regions are squeezed together and you get extremely dense rain in one area and almost nothing right nearby. Highly nonuniform.

For warm fronts, the rain clouds are spread out over a far greater area and the resulting rainfall densities are much more uniform.

Answer (score 1):

Clouds move with the wind. It can be a little like your sprinkler watering a moving spot, and eventually covering the whole yard.

Answer (score 1):

When my region gets days of slow, steady rain from a broad layer of stratus clouds, there isn't much variation: everybody gets days of rain.

But in the summertime, most of my rain comes from cumulus clouds.  These "fair weather" clouds happen when a humid layer of air near the ground heats up faster than the air at higher altitudes.  Eventually the warm air breaks into the cool layer and starts to rise, making puffy clouds, thunderheads, or tornado-bearing storms, depending on ... well, depending on the weather.  Our topography here isn't very complicated, so the locations of these storms can't really be predicted until they've started to happen.  Once they start they can be very localized.  It's not uncommon for me to get caught in a storm so hard that I have to pull off of the road and wait, then drive two or three miles and find that the roads are completely dry.  Two weeks ago I drove fifteen miles to go on a hike, and drove through such a storm: sunny and dry at my house, dark and rainy partway there, sunny and dry at the trailhead.  I did get rained on while I was walking, about an hour later, but I think my house stayed dry.

Many years ago I was driving across the New Mexico desert on a bright summer day, and crested a hill where I could see many miles in every direction. The sky was full of regularly-spaced puffy cumulus clouds, hundreds of them. Exactly one had a grey tail of rain underneath it.  I can't say how intense it was at the ground, because it never rained on the highway.

Rainfall may be uniform on average, but rainstorms have as much variation as clouds do.

Comment: Virga (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virga) is that grey stuff under the cloud - rain that evaporates before it hits the ground. Luckily it seems to contribute to the wonderful rain smell whether it hits the ground or not...

Comment: What a shame that there's a lovely name for visible rain that fails to meet the ground, but if it touches the ground it becomes a "rain shaft." If I were in charge I would call the latter a "caudex": virga is "twig," caudex is "trunk." Watching a distant thunderhead develop from a smooth base to a virga to a rain shaft, over a few tens of seconds, is a remarkable experience; keep your eyes peeled for it.